# how to use Google cloud sql with a windows desktop application developed in free pascal [Lazarus]

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

I develop a windows software with Lazarus/free pascal. this is a simple hotel accounting software. 
I am using Mysql 5.5. I have googled for cloud storage to use in my application. I select goolge app engine cloud sql. Now I have a question that will it work or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can whitelist IP addresses you want to be able to connect to your Cloud SQL instance. See [this article](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external) for more information.